# How to Delete Rows based on a condition from raw files in SSIS ( 2008)

Tags: ssis

I have created a final raw files based on two input tables in SSIS 2008, I need to delete some rows where columnA<>ColumnB present in this file.

How can I achieve this, please advise.

Comment: By "delete," do you mean that some of the rows coming from your input tables should not be put into the output file?

Comment: yes exactly, but I will use these rows to get those rows from input table & copy them to destination db table.

Comment: Doesn't sound like it's a *final* file then. The answer could be as simple as a Conditional Split in the process that creates the output file to shunt the rows that don't meet that criteria into nothingness. It might be that you need to use the output file as an input file for a new process, again with the Conditional Split or possibly some other approach. Please try to restate your problem so that we can more clearly identify approaches for you. Source table definitions, RDBMS, file output format, sample data and general constraints would improve this question.

Comment: Thanks @billinkc, you gave me almost final answer. I used Expression in "Conditional Split" as   `code` (ISNULL(Dest_OrderNumber) ==  TRUE ) || ((ISNULL(Desti_Cnt) ? 0 : Desti_Cnt) != (ISNULL(CNT) ? 0 : CNT))  `code` , but it returned rows that has exactly match

Comment: @billinkc , Kindly put your comment in the answer, I need to mark this as answered, Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer could be as simple as a Conditional Split in the process that creates the output file to shunt the rows that don't meet that criteria into nothingness. It might be that you need to use the output file as an input file for a new process, again with the Conditional Split or possibly some other approach.